# Laravel and Mailgun doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mailgun

Before production version I used mailtrap to test my emails and everything worked like it should be, but today I uploaded my website to a public server and decided to use mailgun, I know its not so simple like `mailtrap.io`, but still. Anyway I verified my account and can now send 10k emails per month. Not bad, but the thing is when I try to send an email I get a notification that the email was sent, but there is no email in any inbox.

My `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myEmail
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

My `services.php` file

return [

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('myDomain'),
    'secret' => env('secretKey'),
],

'ses' => [
    'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
],

'sparkpost' => [
    'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
],

'stripe' => [
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
],
```

];

One of the functions:

```
public function store(StoreListingContactFormRequest $request, Area $area, Listing $listing){

        Mail::to($listing->user)->queue(
            new ListingContactCreated($listing,
                $request->name,
                $request->email,
                $request->number,
                $request->message
            )
        );
        return back()->withSuccess("Teie sõnum on edukalt saadetud firmale {$listing->user->name}");
    }
```

Another one:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
    }

    public function index(Area $area, Listing $listing){
        return view('listings.share.index', compact('listing'));
    }

    public function store(StoreListingShareFormRequest $request, Area $area, Listing $listing){

        collect(array_filter($request->emails))->each(function($email) use ($listing, $request){
            Mail::to($email)->queue(
                new ListingShared($listing, $request->user(), $request->messages)
            );
        });

        return redirect()->route('listings.show',[$area, $listing])->withSuccess('Kuulutus on jagatud edukalt!');
    }
```

Comment: do you have in your env file myDomain and secretKey? You  are reffering on them in config file.

Comment: Yes, in myDomain = ehitusparing.ee, secretKey = secretToken that i got from mailgun dashboard

Comment: Log into Mailgun and check the logs to see if the message has been accepted and delivered.

Comment: Weird, its says. IT LOOKS LIKE THERE ARE NO LOGS ASSOCIATED WITH THIS DOMAIN!

Comment: Is queue working right on your production server? Try send mail without queue.

Comment: How to enable queue in my production server. Do you mean crontab? In local server with valet i dont need to enable anything.

Comment: If sending works great. Then you don't need to worry. It sometimes happens that emails are late (experienced using mailgun also). But if it takes lot of time, contact mailgun support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems the error is here

> MAIL_USERNAME=myEmail
>
> MAIL_PASSWORD=myPassword

MAIL_USERNAME should be not your email but Default SMTP Login from your domain settings page. And Default Password on the same page for MAIL_PASSWORD

> 'domain' => env('myDomain'),

here you need to enter not your site's domain but the domain you've registered on mailgun, something like mg.exmaple.com

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks!